# Why is backward Euler more stable?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

I'm new to the idea of solving ODEs using the backward Euler. I have a system which I solve using the Backward Euler (actually backward Euler + Newton's method since I can't find a closed form solution).

I understand the math involved in solving it, i.e. how to rearrange the equations to get $\vec{x}_{n+1}$, the position at time $n+1$. However, I'm not sure WHY it works.

Given the equation:

$\vec{x}_{n+1} = \vec{x}_n + \Delta t f(t, \vec{x}_{n+1})$ (backward Euler)

compared to

$\vec{x}_{n+1} = \vec{x}_n + \Delta t f(t, \vec{x}_{n})$ (forward Euler)

Why is backward Euler more stable? why does solving for $\vec{x}_{n+1}$ implicitly like that, searching for an equilibrium, produce unlimited stability?

EDIT:

The ODE looks like this:

$\vec{P}_{n+1}^i = \vec{P}_n^i + \Delta t [ \sum_{j \not = i} K (\vec{P}_{n}^j - \vec{P}_n^i) + \sum_{j \not = i} \frac{G(\vec{P}_{n}^i - \vec{P}_n^j)}{|\vec{P}_{n}^j - \vec{P}_n^i|^2}]$

For a bunch of particles (each being $i$) in two dimensions (so each position $\vec{P} = [x, y]^T$).

So basically for each particle I have an attraction force from all other particles and a repulsion force from all other particles. Closed form solution doesn't seem possible for this when I substitute all the $\vec{P}_n^i$ with $\vec{P}_{n+1}^i$ (except the first one, of course).

Also, I'm aware to make it a true Backward Euler I'd have to solve the state of all the system, otherwise my stability isn't really unconditional.

However, if I were to solve this as a system, why does using the backward Euler give increased stability?

Comment: The key is the *kind* of problem that you're trying to solve.  What does the actual ODE look like?

Comment: I gave more details now, but basically I have the usual spring and gravity system designed to spread out a graph over an area

Comment: With a force your ODE should be second order, $\ddot x=a(x)=F(x)/m=-\nabla V(x)/m$, your equation is (almost) the explicit Euler update of the velocities, $v_{n+1}=v_n+Δt\,a(x_n)$. Check Verlet integration $x_{n+1}=2x_n-x_{n-1}+Δt^2\,a(x_n)$ in all its variants for an alternative.

Comment: What do we know about the coefficient $K$ and its sign/magnitude?

Comment: In any case, it might be helpful to know that this phenomenon is sometimes called [stiffness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware about stiff systems, and that for regular Euler integration the system explodes if K is too large in relation to the time step. But why does using the Backward Euler prevent that?
I understand specifically for the spring example since as $\Delta t$ approaches infinity, the system stabilizes. but is there a more abstract answer for why stiff systems experience this increased stability with Backward Euler

Answer (score 1):

There is *plenty* of literature out there discussing the stability of ODE integrators. A good intro to the topic might be [these lecture notes](https://www.epfl.ch/labs/anchp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/part2-1.pdf), which consider linear ODEs first, introducing the concept of A and L stability.

For a nonlinear ODE like yours, you could start by looking into [this site](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Non-linear_stability_of_numerical_methods). There, you find the concept of B and algebraic stability. This can lead you to [this article](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0718051), which presents conditions under which different integrators work or not.